# Cordova ios File Transfer Error: The request timed out

Tags: ios, cordova, file-transfer

I'm using the FileTransfer plugin for downloading files.the issue  is that with large files I have this error

```
FileTransferError {
body = "";
code = 3;
"http_status" = 0;
source = "https://api.serveur.com/api/Download/Boite%20%C3%A0%20outils/vid%C3%A9os/4-box-metiers-neutre.mp4";
target = "file:///Users/msuser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AE92034C-D2D6-4067-A02B-EB21E2C29E14/data/Containers/Data/Application/F3AEFA35-6B7A-441A-A0EF-B5EFB7348C56/Documents/Download/4-box-metiers-neutre.mp4";}
2015-06-10 16:14:21.976 apps[27281:159543] File Transfer Error: The request timed out.
```

the same issue is asked here but without solution [Cordova. FileTransfer plugin. How to catch connection timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446950/cordova-filetransfer-plugin-how-to-catch-connection-timeout-error)

Comment: It seems that the problem comes from your server and not from the plugin. Have you tried to execute this transfer from a web page with a classic ajax call (changing the timeout) ? If you receive your files in PHP for example and that you let the 30s php default execution timeout and/or max upload size lower than the file you send, it won't work.

Comment: I don't think it comes from the server, because downloading the same file in android application works well, but in iOS Apps give the timeout error

Comment: Indeed I thought it was an uploading and not a downloading.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?, I get the same thing here